# отследить откуда совершен переход в storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Есть один контроллер, например, `"C"`, в который можно попасть из двух мест `"A"` и `"B"`. 
Переходам в `storyboard` присвоены `identyfire`, например, `"iA"` и `"iB"`, но при переходе с `А` нужно выполнить дополнительный метод.

Вопрос такой: как отследить c какого контроллера совершен переход в `"C"`, и как будет выглядеть условие `if`, чтобы вызвать дополнительный метод?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант в Вашем "С" контроллере сделать `Bool` проперти, далее в контроллерах "А" и "В" в методе `prepareForSegue` указать для данной проперти значение `YES/NO`

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        // Получаем контроллер
        CController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        // устанавливаем значение
        [vc setYourBoolProperty:YES];
    }
}
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
           if segue!.identifier == "MySegue" {
              let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController 
let viewController = nav.topViewController as! СController
                viewController.yourBoolProperty = true
            }

    }
```

Ну и далее выполняете в `if-else` необходимые действия

Comment: спасибо за хорошую идею! 
интегрировал её в проект и получаю ошибку такого плана:

Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController',

а в коде выделяется красным строка создания let viewController:VC = segue....

Comment: Сделайте так: `let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let viewController = nav.topViewController as! СController`. Изменил ответ